# Python Index and Bounds error using data set

Tags: python-3.x

Our class is using Python as a solution tool for models. However, this is my first time with python or any programming language since VB in 1997 so I'm struggling. We have the following code provided to us.

```
from numpy import loadtxt, array, ones, column_stack
from numpy import dot, sqrt
from scipy.linalg import inv
from scipy.stats import norm, t


f = loadtxt('text data.raw')

y = f[:,4]
n = y.size
x = array([f[:,2],f[:,8],f[:,4]])
one = ones(n)
#xa = column_stack([one,f[:,3],f[:,4]])
xa = column_stack([one,x.T])
k = xa.shape[1] 

xx = dot(xa.T,xa)
invx = inv(xx)
xy = dot(xa.T,y)
b = dot(invx,xy)

# Compute cov(b)
e = y - dot(xa,b)
s2 = dot(e.T,e)/(n-k)
covb = invx*s2

# Compute t-stat
tstat = b[1]/sqrt(covb[1][1])

#compute p-value
p = 1 - norm.cdf(tstat,0,1)
pt = 1 - t.cdf(tstat,88)
```

Our data set is a 10x88 matrix. Our goal is to create a linear program and find a few answers. On our data column 1 is already set to price which in our linear program is our desired out put and I need to use column 3,4, and 5. as my x1,x2, and x3. I'm not sure how or what line 9 and 11 values need to be changed to in order to accomplish that task nor am I currently understanding what those two lines are specifically calling for or doing in the program. Again, I'm not familiar with programming.

Everything I try generally yields an error similar to

```
IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 5
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide the fullstack error.